# Parent Lkp Id empty when custom New page is used in Salesforce1. Why?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, master-detail, salesforce1-platform

I have a master detail `Child__c` object with a custom page override for New and Edit. 
This page is used in desktop and mobile Salesforce1 context.

My problem: the page doesn't work in Salesforce1 as `{!Child__c.mdr_Parent__c}` is empty in Salesforce1 but populated with the correct parent id on the desktop.

I have a hunch why. On the desktop mouse clicks make real HTTP request to other pages while mobile seems to be a one-page app. At least from looking at the request params I see that the lkip param is missing:

```
        Desktop:  {
            CF00NF000000AX8Cz=Test 1 Woche New York, 
            CF00NF000000AX8Cz_lkid=a00F000000CKcSd, 
            RecordType=012F0000001CV6V, 
            core.apexpages.devmode.url=1, 
            ent=01IF0000002H0KJ, 
            retURL=/apex/up2go_ite__travelView?id=a00F000000CKcSd&sfdc.override=1&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1, 
            save_new=1, 
            scontrolCaching=1, 
            sfdc.override=1
        }

        Salesforce1 (on Mobile Device):  {
            RecordType=012F0000001CV6V, 
            ent=01IF0000002H0KJ, 
            isdtp=p1, 
            nonce=b6779545cc07c1bbde906a6d8b470bb9001dd299932dbb4807931f410ea89533, 
            save_new=1, 
            sfdc.override=1, 
            sfdcIFrameHost=hybrid, 
            sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://na10.salesforce.com
        }

        Salesforce1 (on one/one.app): {
            CF00NF000000AX8Cz=Test 1 Woche New York, 
            CF00NF000000AX8Cz_lkid=a00F000000CKcSdIAL, 
            RecordType=012F0000001CQAY, ent=01IF0000002H0KJ, 
            isdtp=p1, 
            nonce=e01def97cfdb91593f0ac15345849c561fcabee973fc5b46ed00512562a55aa5, 
            save_new=1, 
            sfdc.override=1, 
            sfdcIFrameHost=web, 
            sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://na10.salesforce.com, 
            ...
        }
```

The funny thing is that the Salesforce1 emulator even has a mix of both parameter and contains the relevant _lkip param. Indeed it works there.